# How do I create sequences/series with user input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

### Taking me a 'while', but i only have a day.

For a math project, I am trying to generate an arithmetic and geometric series/sequence with JavaScript.  The thing that makes this challenging is that I am using user input to determine different parts of the formula I am using to generate each sequence.  I have tried to run the formulas, but I found out i was running strings through them and not numbers.  How do I generate my sequences/series and still use user input?
PS, these are my formulas: (a1 is first term, d and r are difference/ratio, and n is the nth term)

a1 + d * n

a1 * r^n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. You could map certain strings like `"*"` to a multiplication function or something like that. If you are just inputting in numbers the converting from string to an integer isn't hard.

You could iterate through all of the input, tokenized by a space, and then if you input using brackets, maybe convert to post-fix notation and apply the operations using a stack? But this is impossible without mapping your `"+"`, `"-"` to Javascript operators/functions.